# Android - Application onCreate method - does it ALWAYS get called first?

Tags: android

I am preparing new version of one of my apps, and I made such huge changes in my app, that I need to do some data conversion exactly after update of app as absolutely first thing (before doing anything else). I figured out, that best place to do it would be in my class (which extends Application) in onCreate() method. I tested it few times, and it seems to work ok, but then I read documentation:

> Base class for those who need to maintain global application state. 
>   You can provide your own implementation by specifying its name in 
>   your AndroidManifest.xml's  tag, [b]which will cause 
>   that class to be instantiated for you when the process for your 
>   application/package is created[/b].

It looks like I am right, but I am not quite sure. Can you confirm/disprove it?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it also only runs once during the lifecycle of the app. So what you put in there will be first to run then won't run again unless you restart the app.

Comment: what is 'application'?  The main entry point is always MainActivity, I thought?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Application constructor will be called first.  Then the Application::onCreate() method will be called.   The only exception I know of is if the Application contains a ContentProvider, it can receive calls before the Application does.

This is from here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate()

> public void onCreate ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Called when the application is starting, before
>   any activity, service, or receiver objects (excluding content
>   providers) have been created. Implementations should be as quick as
>   possible (for example using lazy initialization of state) since the
>   time spent in this function directly impacts the performance of
>   starting the first activity, service, or receiver in a process. If you
>   override this method, be sure to call super.onCreate().

Comment: thanks, I accepted your answer as you were first who wrote right answer :)

Comment: I think , onWindowFocusChanged is also called before , onCreate() method .

Comment: @TusharPandey:  I doubt that onWindowFocusChanged is called first.  Remember this is Application::onCreate, not Activity::onCreate.  At this point in the life cycle of the Application there is no window associated with the Application.  In fact if it is being started in order to use a Service or Broadcast receiver(etc.) in the application, there may never be a window associated with this application.

Comment: By `Application contains a ContentProvider`, what do you really mean? The Application class has an inner ContentProvider subclass or App has ContentProviders.

Comment: An "application" is everything in an APK which can include Activities, Services, ContentProviders, BroadcastReceivers, etc.  If you look at your project in Android Studio (or eclipse) and you find classes derived from android.content.ContentProvider, then your Application contains a ContentProvider.   If some other application requests something from that ContentProvider Android may start an instance of your application just to satisfy this request.  In this case the call to Application.onCreate() may not have occurred when the Content Provider handles the request.

Comment: I just found out the hard way that if you register an 'InstallReceiver' it will receive it's 'onReceive' before the Application.onCreate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is right. You should do all your initial app configuration in the `onCreate()` method of the `Application`.
Besides if you use sqllite you can make migration in `onUpgrade` method of the SQLiteOpenHelper.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it, and maybe there are some more relevant options out there, but for the upgrade the following looks promising: `SQLiteOpenHelper.onUpgrade( SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion )`. 
So you can hang your update routines on that. The method you override should fire only when the database upgrade is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The application onCreate method is the first method that is called when the process is started. you can put your code there without any problems.
here the documentation [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate%28%29)

> Called when the application is starting, before any activity, service, or receiver objects (excluding content providers) have been created. Implementations should be as quick as possible since the time spent in this function directly impacts the performance of starting the first activity...

be careful to make all the changes very quickly and be sure that you call the "upgrade" method only once.
Consider also the possibility to put this method in an AsyncTask, if its possible.

Answer (score -5):

No it dosent..say you have activity A(launcher activity) and B...when you launch your app ...A loads starting from onCreate()...and say u started activity B, then it launches B and its onCreate method is executed..but now if you navigate back to A..it will call th onResume activity and not the onCreate..